# What is the property for field Script of C# FontDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

What is the property for this field?
I've tried to use the font dialog for changing font of some text boxes in a Window Form project. But the font is not always be changed when I change this field.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.7. The code is:

```
private void fontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        textBox1.Font = fontDialog.Font;
    }
}
```

Comment: Winforms uses a [wrapper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FontDialog.cs) over winapi common Font dialog. Some functionality is stripped away. You have to use winapi to obtain missing one. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-international-fonts-and-text).